# Converting .sh shellscript file to .bat batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .sh script

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK_FOR="codehaus/xfire/spring"

for i in `find . -name "*jar"`
do
  echo "Looking in $i ..."
  jar tvf $i | grep $LOOK_FOR > /dev/null
  if [ $? == 0 ]
  then
    echo "==> Found \"$LOOK_FOR\" in $i"
  fi
done
```

can someone help me in convert this to .bat script which runs on windows.

Regards,
DH

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "LOOK_FOR=codehaus/xfire/spring"
    for %%a in ("*.jar") do ( 
        echo Looking in %%a
        jar tvf "%%a" | find "%LOOK_FOR%" >nul && echo Found in %%a 
    )
```

Assuming, of course, you have `jar.exe` in the path and the current folder contains the `.jar` files (the same assumptions in the `.sh` file)